# Python - Questions on selenium dropbox with no option and agreement checkbox for web crawling

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl [this website](https://www.acatoday.org/Find-a-Doctor). I need to:

1. Choose one of the options for Techniques
2. Check "I have read and agree to the following disclaimer"
3. Click on Search button
4. Crawl to extract web-addresses

I have a few lines of code so far after a number of tries. To do parts 1 - 3,  I do:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Techniques']/option[text()='Diversified Technique']").click()

checkbox = browser.find_element_by_id("dnn_ctr5517_Clients_Custom_ctl00_cbAgree")
if not checkbox.is_selected():
    checkbox.click()

buttons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Search')]")
if not checkbox.is_selected():
    checkbox.click()
```

This is not working. It does not give me any error but does not produce results either.

**Note**: for Techniques, the options are li instead of options like below for "Microamperage Neural Stimulation":

```
<li class="rcbItem"><label><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Microamperage Neural Stimulation</label></li>
```

How can I get those three options set and get results back?

Thank you.

Comment: So are you trying to tick more than one box or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('dnn_ctr5517_Clients_Custom_ctl00_rcbSkills_Input').click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//label[contains(., "Diversified")]/input').click()

checkbox = browser.find_element_by_id('dnn_ctr5517_Clients_Custom_ctl00_cbAgree')
if not checkbox.is_selected():
  checkbox.click()

searchBtn = browser.find_element_by_id('dnn_ctr5517_Clients_Custom_ctl00_btnSearch')
searchBtn.click()
```

You can repeat the second line if you need to select more than one. You might have to insert a *wait* between the first two lines because it's possible you may get an `Element not visible` exception. Afterwards, you should be able to wait for the results to return.